# How can I sort an array based on a couple parameters?

Tags: javascript

Working on a web game as a hobby. I have an "inventory" which contains pets:

```
interface Pet {
  type: string;
  level: number;
  isFavorite: boolean;
}

allPetSlots = [
  {slotState: INVENTORY_STATE.EQUIPPED, pet: {...},
  {slotState: INVENTORY_STATE.OCCUPIED, pet: {...},
  {slotState: INVENTORY_STATE.OCCUPIED, pet: {...},
  {slotState: INVENTORY_STATE.EMPTY, pet: null,
  {slotState: INVENTORY_STATE.EMPTY, pet: null,
  {slotState: INVENTORY_STATE.EMPTY, pet: null,
  {...}
]
```

I currently have a `sortAll` method that sorts the inventory on these specific criterias:

1. FAVORITED PETS SHOW UP FIRST
2. GROUP BY PET TYPE
3. SORT BY LEVEL desc
4. ALL EMPTY SPOTS SHOW UP AFTER

This is what I have:

```
allPetsSlots
        .sort((a) => (a.state === 'occupied' || a.state === 'equipped' ? -1 : 1))
        .sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.pet?.type < b.pet?.type) return -1;
            if (a.pet?.type > b.pet?.type) return 1;
            return 0;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.pet?.type === b.pet?.type && a.pet?.level > b.pet?.level) return -1;
            if (a.pet?.type === b.pet?.type && a.pet?.level < b.pet?.level) return 1;
            return 0;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.pet?.isFavorite || b.pet?.isFavorite) return -1;
            return 1;
        })
```

While this ***SEEMS*** to work in chrome:
[image]

I'm having some troubles with other browsers. I'm pretty sure my sort function is doing something weird and my brain is extra foggy today.

Would appreciate any help!

```js
const currentPets = [
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 3, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'equipped', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 6, isFavorite: true}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 5, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 6, isFavorite: true}},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 1, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 4, isFavorite: true}},
]

const sortAll = () => {
  currentPets
    .sort((a) => (a.state === 'occupied' || a.state === 'equipped' ? -1 : 1))
        .sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.pet?.type < b.pet?.type) return -1;
            if (a.pet?.type > b.pet?.type) return 1;
            return 0;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.pet?.type === b.pet?.type && a.pet?.level > b.pet?.level) return -1;
            if (a.pet?.type === b.pet?.type && a.pet?.level < b.pet?.level) return 1;
            return 0;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.pet?.isFavorite || b.pet?.isFavorite) return -1;
            return 0;
        })
}

console.log('sorted', currentPets)
```

Comment: Only the *last* `sort` really works! You can't sort an array in multiple steps, all the logic needs to be in one callback.

Comment: Oh interesting... its so weird it works in chrome...

Comment: As you say: it *happens to*.

Comment: Of course you can sort in multiple steps, but you never take `undefined` into consideration, which will always return "false", even if comparing to a boolean. So  if it's `undefined` compared to  `true`, the code won't sort at all.

Comment: I figured the first sort would handle the `undefined` since it would sort the occupied/equipped slots to the front and the empty slots to the back. Thats why I include the optional chaining in the subsequent sorts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take `undefined` into consideration. I think it's a waste of resources to sort an array multiple times, because of the numerous loops that the sortings will demand.

I changed just the `isFavorite` sort for you. If I were you, I would just continue with more code under the first checked property (isFavorite).

```js
const currentPets = [
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 3, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'equipped', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 6, isFavorite: true}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 5, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 6, isFavorite: true}},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 1, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 4, isFavorite: true}},
]


const sortAll = () => {
  let tempA, tempB;

  return currentPets
    .sort((a, b) => {
        tempA = a.pet?.isFavorite
        tempB = b.pet?.isFavorite

        // you should refactor this if statement
        if (tempA !== tempB) {
          if (typeof tempA == 'undefined') { return 1  }
          if (typeof tempB == 'undefined') { return -1 }
          if (tempA < tempB)               { return 1  }
          if (tempA > tempB)               { return -1 }
        }

        // tempA = a.pet?.type
        // tempB = b.pet?.type
        //if (tempA !== tempB) {
          // ...
        //}

        return 0
    })
}

console.log('sorted', sortAll());
```

And how is how it should look like if you refactored the code:

```js
const currentPets = [
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 3, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'equipped', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 6, isFavorite: true}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'quartz', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 5, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'obsidian', level: 6, isFavorite: true}},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'empty', pet: null},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 1, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 2, isFavorite: false}},
  { state: 'occupied', pet: { type: 'agate', level: 4, isFavorite: true}},
]


const sortAll = (arr) => {
  const UNSORTED = 0;
  let   result   = 0;

  return arr
    .sort((a, b) => {
        result = compareProperties(a.pet?.isFavorite, b.pet?.isFavorite)

        // if (result == UNSORTED) {
        //  result = compareProperties(a.pet?.type, b.pet?.type)
        // }
        
        // if (result == UNSORTED) {
        // ...

        return result
    })
}

const compareProperties = (tempA, tempB) => {
  if (tempA !== tempB) {
    if (typeof tempA == 'undefined') { return 1  }
    if (typeof tempB == 'undefined') { return -1 }
    if (tempA < tempB)               { return 1  }
    if (tempA > tempB)               { return -1 }
  }

  return 0
}

console.log('sorted', sortAll(currentPets));
```